# Determine if ui layout pane has a scrollbar

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible to determine if a UI.Layout pane has a scrollbar? My center pane has DIVs; one of the DIVs contains a jqGrid that I'm trying to auto resize. Playing around with resize events, the grid resizes properly if there is no scrollbar. I believe if I could determine whether or not a scrollbar is there, I can better resize the grid.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can create a new function like this to check for the existance of a scrollbar

```
$.fn.hasVerticalScrollBar = function () { 
  if (this[0].clientHeight < this[0].scrollHeight) { 
    return true 
  } else { 
    return false 
  } 
}  

$.fn.hasHorizontalScrollBar = function() { 
  if (this[0].clientWidth < this[0].scrollWidth) { 
    return true 
  } else { 
    return false 
  } 
}
```

Usage:

```
alert($('#mydivid').hasHorizontalScrollBar()); 
alert($('#mydivid').hasVerticalScrollBar());
```

Comment: Thank you John.  But clientHeight and scrollHeight return undefined.  Is it the way the UI Layout panes are setup?

Comment: @DrZ .. This was just a push in the right direction. UI layout panes is probably not the correct container.  You would need to look at the rendered HTML and determine where the jqGrid actually has the scrollbars attached.  I actually did this once before and these are the exact functions I used.  I just cant remember exactly where the scrollbars are rendered.

Comment: I just looked at one of my grids and it seems the the jqGrid Scrollbars actually appear in the div with the class `ui-jqgrid-bdiv`

Comment: Actually I get your meaning but I just checked to see if my function calls would work on ui layout panes and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Thank you again John.  The scrollbar that I'm trying to locate is the one in the center pane.  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6032362/ScrollBar.png shows an image of what I'm dealing with.  The grid is outlined in green and the scrollbar in red.  I really appreciate you taking the time to help.

Comment: I would love to help you but with out being able to see the HTML I cannot determine what element the scrollbar is actually located on. Certainly the Image helps but it would be more helpful to see a the HTML of the element that contains the scrollbar. Perhaps you could create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Hi John.  I hope I did this right (I've never used jsfiddle).  http://jsfiddle.net/dzangger67/ruXnS/  I'm not sure where to put the function in jsfiddle.  But you can see that the center pane does have a scrollbar.  Hope this helps.  Thank you John.

Comment: @DrZ... I figured out the issue it was my function.  I have made the correct modifications in the answer above and also modified your fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ruXnS/5/

Comment: That works!  Thank you so much John!  I really appreciate you sticking with me on this.